# generate XML file form oracle table

Tags: xml, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I create a Store procedure for Generating a XML file from table please check below  Store procedure

```
create or replace
procedure dump_pcd (
V_TABLE_NAME IN varchar2,
v_FLAG OUT NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN
DECLARE
xt_data xmltype;
v_ctx dbms_xmlgen.ctxHandle;
rc_data sys_refcursor;
v_file UTL_FILE.file_type;

BEGIN
-- v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME ||'.xml', 'A');
-- v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || '.xml', 'A');


v_file := UTL_FILE.fopen('MYXML', V_TABLE_NAME || '.xml', 'W');
UTL_FILE.put_line(v_file, '<XML><'||V_TABLE_NAME||'></'||V_TABLE_NAME||'> <RECORDS>');






OPEN rc_data FOR
'select * from '|| V_TABLE_NAME||' ';

v_ctx := dbms_xmlgen.newContext (rc_data);
DBMS_XMLGEN.SETNULLHANDLING(v_ctx,null);

DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowsettag(v_ctx, 'RECORDS');
DBMS_XMLGEN.setrowtag(v_ctx, 'RECORD');

xt_data := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType (v_ctx);
dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);

dbms_xslprocessor.clob2file(xt_data.getclobval( ), 'MYXML', ''||V_TABLE_NAME||'.xml');
v_FLAG := 1;


EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
dbms_xmlgen.closeContext (v_ctx);
v_FLAG := 0;

end ;

END dump_pcd;
```

its works but after some rows like 60000 rows it shows error 
I also replace < , > , & char but still error occur

```
ora-30625 method dispatch on null self argument is disallowed
```

Please Check code and help here

Comment: sounds like you have a `xt_data.getclobval()` returning NULL and IF I was the clob2file function, I would throw an ora-30625. By the way, writing files with the database server, somehow always causes me to shiver (hopefully you configured your UTL_FILE correctly)... you could use nearly any middleware to dump those xmls but not the database/server itself

Comment: how to solve this issue ? i not not getting

Comment: forget my comment, are you DUMPING a whole table to XML and try to write it into a SINGLE(!) file via UTL-File? Please dont backup/export tables like this, use _exp_ for that: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch01.htm

Comment: my table columns value  have char < , > , &  So how to remove it ? if any function in xml and what about Cdata tag

Comment: if its only for those special chars, use http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlgen.htm#i1013328